# Need to paste some html tags from one file to several differents

Tags: php, html, include

I have some html file like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<!-- article TEXTS BLOCK -->
<section id="text-article-1">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
</section>
<section id="text-article-2">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
</section>
<section id="text-article-3">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
</section>
</html>
```

And I have about 20 php files like

```
<? require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ."/block/lib.php";?>
<? require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ."/block/rules.php";?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <!-- HEAD -->
        <? require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ."/block/head/meta.php";?>
    <!-- END HEAD -->
</head>
<body>
<section id = "article-1">
    <? require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ."/content/gallery-1.php";?>
    <!-- PLACE FOR ARTICLES 1 -->
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

And I want to extract sections with different articles from my html-file and paste it to different php files. So I need something like INCLUDE but not all file but just section with needed ID.
Don't have enough knowledge to think up some solution...

Comment: Are you able to change how the article content is stored? A better way would probably be in a database but if you still want to go with files, then possibly having a separate file for each content and naming it respectively (i.e. "article-1.html", "article-2.html"). That way you can include on what's required.

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery and do the following

1. Add a div with `id=sectionContainer`
2. use `$("#sectionContainer").load("htmlfile.html #text-article-<?= $id ?>")`

which will load the div with the section with `id=text-article-1` if the php $id is 1 etc

- You can use CSS and hide all sections and show relevant id

  ```
  section { display: none }
  #text-article-<?= $id ?> { display:block }
  ```

which will only show the section with `id=text-article-1` if the php $id is 1 etc

Comment: I'd like the option with jQuery. Can u be a little more detail...

Answer (score 0):

Write your codes in one Php file and include that file into your other files by using inculde 'filename.php' like this.

`<?php include 'filename.php' ?>`

Comment: I can't. Logic is writing text articles in one place. Php files is in different directories and i include different galereys and different articles. Galery each one in different file but articles in one...

Comment: ok i will share you if i found another way